# the figure below shows the graph of g, sketch the graph of g^-1

Tags: calculus, functions

the figure below shows the graph of g, sketch the graph of g^-1

[image]

I try with that , that correct ?

[image]

Comment: Your graph is kind of confusing, I see that you rotated it and that would incorrect. When graphing inverses you reflect each point in our function about $y=x$.

Comment: Why was an 8-year-old question bumped by the bot?

Comment: @Mike: Because it did not have any answers with positive votes. Those questions get bumped every so often automatically.

Comment: That makes sense @ArturoMagidin . Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: That's the same graph. You want to transpose the $x$ and $y$ axes. Reflect the graph across the line $y=x$ and you will have your graph.

Comment: No, it isn't. That's is still the graph of $g$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to draw the grapoh of inverse function of g? 
That would be the reflection in the line y=x which is the dotted line drawn. What you have done is the reflection in origin.

Inverse function if defined as the function that relates the image of an element in the codomain to its pre-image in the domain. So graphically it means to interchange the x&y coordinates of each and every point. Reflecting in the line y=x is equivalent to interchanging co ,ordinates